Need help to setup rtc-ds1302 in device tree on RaspberryPi
I need to wire a RTC DS1302 on a RaspberryPi 1B running Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye. I can make it work from user space and bitbanging the gpio, and update the OS clock accordingly during boot.
However, the state of the art will be to make it work in kernel space and have the RTC in the device tree.
Note that,

it is SPI-3wire interface (half duplex, there is only one data line for in & out)
cs active high
lsb (Least Significant Bit) first

On the other hand,

I've read people saying that this SPI mode is not supported by the SPI controller hardware. It's seems to me it is not a correct statement, because BCM2835 datasheet does have configuration registers to support this mode.
So it could be possible that the chip does not need bitbang, but can be wired to the native SPI pins instead.

RTC / GPIO wiring,

GPIO 27 used as SPI SCK and is wired to RTC CLK pin
GPIO 18 used as SPI half duplex MIMO and is wired to RTC DAT
GPIO 17 used as SPI CS and is wired to RTC CE
GPIO 22 not used as SPI MISO or MOSI but can be sacrificed because the overlay must define a pin (this is a required parameters)

Here are a few links for references;
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/spi/spi-gpio.txt
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/rtc/maxim-ds1302.txt
Having said that, I'm not sure what I'm doing and it obviously does not work.
I need your guidance on this,

Edit the file /etc/modules and add the SPI-GPIO & RTC-DS1302 kernel modules
sudo nano /etc/modules
Add the following lines


spi-gpio
rtc-ds1302


Create a dtbo overlay to map the rtc-ds1302 on spi in the device tree
nano spi-gpio-rtc-ds1302.dts

Add the following content, I think the error is somewhere here
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/{
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835";
    fragment@0 {
        target-path = "/";
        __overlay__ {
        
            spi {
                compatible = "spi-gpio";
                #address-cells = <0x1>;
                ranges;

                sck-gpios = <&gpio 27 0>;
                miso-gpios = <&gpio 18 0>;
                mosi-gpios = <&gpio 22 0>;
                cs-gpios = <&gpio 17 0>;
                num-chipselects = <1>;

                ds1302 {
                    compatible = "maxim,ds1302";
                    reg = <0>;
                    spi-max-frequency = <500000>;
                    spi-3wire;
                    spi-lsb-first;
                    spi-cs-high;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};


Compile the dtbo
dtc -@ -I dts -O dtb -o spi-gpio-rtc-ds1302.dtbo spi-gpio-rtc-ds1302.dts

Add the overlay to /boot/overlays/
sudo cp spi-gpio-rtc-ds1302.dtbo /boot/overlays/

Add the overlay in /boot/config.txt
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
Add the line


dtoverlay=spi-gpio-rtc-ds1302


Reboot
sudo reboot

Check loaded modules
lsmod shows,


Module                  Size  Used by
...
rtc_ds1302              3692  0
spi_gpio                7244  0
spi_bitbang             5316  1 spi_gpio
...

We see that spi_bitbang has been loaded automatically because it is a dependency of spi_gpio.
But rtc_ds1302 and spi_gpio kernel modules are not used.
ls /dev/ does not show any rtc device
and of course,  hwclock --verbose fails
hwclock from util-linux 2.36.1
System Time: 1719058842.181058
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Trying to open: /dev/rtc
Trying to open: /dev/misc/rtc
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.

and timedatectl status shows not RTC time
               Local time: Sat 2024-06-22 14:41:18 CEST
           Universal time: Sat 2024-06-22 12:41:18 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/Paris (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no


If you're trying to connect this SPI device to an SPI master controller, then assigning its DT (child) node to a parent node with a driver identified by compatible = "spi-gpio"; makes no sense at all. AFAIK you should be choosing for the parent node either BCM2835 SPI controller or BCM2835 SPI auxiliary controller/

But if you intend to bitbang this connection, then why all the rambling about an SPI controller? IOW clearly state what you are trying to do (besides add DT nodes.).

hi @sawdust thanks. What I'm trying to do to: I need to define a SPI device on pins 27 (clock), 18 (I/O data), 17 (chip select) and tell the kernel there is a ds1302 plugged on it. I am not trying to use the hardware SPI interface.

So far, for troubleshooting, you have done little. If there was a race or game, what you've done so far is like only looking at the results, e.g. the final score. If you want to know what actually happened, then you need to watch the replay. The replay of what happened in this case (that you need to review) is the boot log, aka syslog, that is retrievable using the dmesg command (assuming the syslog has not wrapped).

I'm not sure about that ranges; line in the controller. Also, it should have #size-cells = <0>;.
